# Using a custom template with a TableItem in Carbon Design (Angular) not yielding expected functionality

Tags: angular

[According to the IBM Carbon Design System docs,](https://angular.carbondesignsystem.com/documentation/classes/TableItem.html#info) one can define an `ng-template` and reference it using `@ViewChild` and a `protected` variable.

Then, when defining a `new TableItem`, one should reference this variable and attach data associated with the template via the attribute `let-data`, in summary:

```js
import {
  TableItem,
  TableHeaderItem
} from 'carbon-components-angular';

/* ... */

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('customItemTemplate')
  protected customItemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  /* ... */

initialiseTable(records: any) {
    this.model = new TableModel();
    this.model.header = [
      new TableHeaderItem({ data: 'Column name' }),
      /* ... */
    ];


    tableRow = [
      new TableItem({ data: { name: 'Full details', link: '/record/' }, template: this.customItemTemplate }),
      /* ... */
    ];

    this.model.data = [tableRow];

}
```

And in my component's HTML I have the following `ng-template`:

```html
<ng-template #customItemTemplate let-data="data">
  <a [routerLink]="data.link">{{data.name}}</a>
</ng-template>
```

I've tried switching between different versions: 9.0.0 and 10.0.0.rc.0.

When I looked at the view, where the custom template ought to be, I see `[object Object]`.

**Can anyone help me fix this so that my template inserts properly and I can provide a link to another view?**

**Update**: I have filed this as an issue on GitHub and had a really fast response. I was asked to offer a reduced demo which you can find [via Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/7jp3xnmqq0). Related [GitHub issue here](https://github.com/IBM/carbon-components-angular/issues/455)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue!

Believe it or not, it has to do with the code provided by IBM's documentation on **Pagination**.

The code in question which is causing issues by default with custom templates is this, used for the pagination functionality in the demo:

```js
  protected prepareData(data: Array<Array<any>>) {
      // create new data from the service data
      let newData = [];
      data.forEach(dataRow => {
          let row = [];
          dataRow.forEach(dataElement => {
              row.push(new TableItem({
                  data: dataElement,
                  template: typeof dataElement === "string" ? undefined : this.paginationTableItemTemplate
                  // your template can handle all the data types so you don't have to conditionally set it
                  // you can also set different templates for different columns based on index
              }));
          });
          newData.push(row);
      });
      return newData;
  }
```

For reference, [here is the relevant documentation](https://angular.carbondesignsystem.com/documentation/components/Table.html). If you scroll down to the header "Use pagination as table footer" you'll see the code I'm talking about :)

**Solution**

The function needs to check for the type coming through when `prepareData` is called during pagination:

```js
protected prepareData(data: Array<Array<any>>) {
    // create new data from the service data
    const newData: Array<Array<TableItem>> = [];
    data.forEach(dataRow => {
      const row: Array<TableItem> = [];
      dataRow.forEach(dataElement => {
        let template;
        if (dataElement.template) {
          template = dataElement.template;
        } else if (typeof dataElement === 'string') {
          template = undefined;
        } else {
          template = this.paginationTableItemTemplate;
        }

        row.push(
          new TableItem({
            data: dataElement.data,
            template: template
          })
        );
      });
      newData.push(row);
    });
    return newData;
  }
```

And now it works like a charm.

I have updated the team via GH and will see about a PR for the docs on this--it will not be uncommon that people copy the code and forget about it, like I did. It was only when I stripped back all functionality the custom templates started working, then I worked up from base principles.